# Как сделать из jsf Json?

Tags: javascript, ajax, json, jsf

Всем Добрый вечер!

Не подскажите как сделать данные из БД которые отображаются на  `jsf` в `Json` для последующие подачи её в скрипт .Мне хотелосьбы узнать про переход из `Jsf` в `Json`.Если не сложно покажите пару легких примеров ...Благодарю .

Comment: т.е. вам надо данные из БД представить в виде JSON?

Comment: нет нет .я получаю данные из сервера в формате string int и так далее обычно джавоски.хочу затем их передать в js но для этого их надо сделать json вот как это незнаю(

Comment: устал уже искать и головне вит не откажусь от помощи

Comment: Что выхотите? Выполнять из jsf ajax запрос, возврвщающий json? Вывод json в страницу сразу? Или чтобы jsf возвращал вместо html json?

Comment: да да сделать ajax запрос возващающий json

Comment: ничего толковго или обьясняющего не нашел

Comment: Какая библиотека jsf? Стандартная, Primefaces, ещё что-то? Primefaces например использует jquery, можно воспользоваться им. Есть ли сервис, который возвращает json или его тоже надо? Запрос должен срабатывать по нажатию кнопки или другое событие?

Comment: @elik почитайте про jQuery и JavaScript. плюс добавьте на стороне сервера, то что возвращает json.

Comment: Сергей обычный Jsf стандартный .через хибернайт получаю данные из бд размещаю их в табле юдальше хочу по нажатию обычной кнопки послать данные в джава скрипт но для этого надо сделать эти данные json

Comment: Mikhail Vasymyan Jquery мне поможет вэтом ?? он совместимс с jsf ?

Comment: @elik для ajax точно поможет. он совместим.

Comment: хм понятно но хотелось бы более чего нибудь неужели так сложно передать параметр из java в java script >?

Comment: @elik `хочу по нажатию обычной кнопки послать данные в джава скрипт`. Т.е. данные есть, скрипт есть, надо только их в json перевести? Что тогда это за данные? Строка таблицы? Или правильнее будет будет так `хочу получить данные ajax-запросом и передать их в скрипт`?

Comment: хочу получить данные ajax-запросом и передать их в скрипт

Comment: А что минус-то поставили? JSF сам по себе сложен, так к нему ещё и прибегают в первую очередь те, кто не дружит с javascript. Без бутылки не разберёшься.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Скачиваете jquery (условно jquery.js). Помещаете например в `/WEB-INF/resources/js/`
(Обязательно часть `/WEB-INF/resources/`)

```
...
<h:head>
    ...
    <h:outputScript name="js/jquery.js"/>
    <h:outputScript>
        function jsonSuccess(data) {
            // здесь можете передать data в свой скрипт
        }
    </h:outputScript>
</h:head>

<h:body>
    ...
    <h:button onclick="$.getJSON('#{jsonUrl}', { param1: 'value1', param2: '#{value2}' }, jsonSuccess); return false;"/>
    ...
</h:body>
...
```

Примерно так. Для начала сойдёт.
В jquery для запроса json есть функция `$.getJSON` (упрощённая версия $.ajax). Вызываем её в обработчике нажатия на кнопку.
`jsonUrl` - это url, который выдаёт json. Можете и строкой написать (`example.com`) если не надо вычислять из el-выражения.

Надеюсь ясно как из java передать переменные в скрипт на jsf-странице. Точно так же как в компоненты JSF с помощью EL `#{}`.

При получении json-а вызывается функция `jsonSuccess`, в которой делайте с ним что хотите. Но вы можете вместо `jsonSuccess` передать сразу функцию своего скрипта, если она принимает нужные параметры.

Чтобы при нажатии на кнопку в завершении не срабатывала функция jsf, надо чтобы обработчик вернул false (ну как обычно принято было раньше в обработчиках событий). Поэтому `return false` после вызова `$.getJSON`.

Comment: Сергей Огромное человеческое Спасибо!Да за что минус поставли незнаю,но я увен это вбудущем ответ поможет многим .Я только только в Webe - перешел с андроида поэтому пока сложнов с одной стороны дела со скриптами с друой синхронизация и все такое .Благодраю за помощь !